# R - list of mixed type to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, shopify

Using the Shopifyr package, I've gotten a list of orders in the format of a thousand element list of lists of attributes. These attributes are named and have consistent types in each instance, but some are themselves lists of varying length.

I've tried `stack(my.list)`, but get

```
Error in rep.int(factor(names(x), unique(names(x))), lengths(x)) : 
  invalid 'times' value
```

Comment: You need to make [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with data to get a useful answer.

Comment: For general info on how to work with lists in R, I recommend [the core purrr lessons here](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls00_inspect-explore.html). Also, try looking up `lapply` and basic list syntax.

Comment: You should check out the `shopr_get_orders()` function from [shopr](https://github.com/GormAnalysis/shopr). It'll parse and clean the results for you.